# Adjective for something that puts you on edge?

Tags: adjectives

For school, I'm taking some online courses, which are graded almost completely by 10 question quizzes that cover each lesson. Any question wrong is a drop of 10%, so it's very important to try to get everything right. Unfortunately, the questions are often quite ambiguous and opinionated, and leave me stuck between two choices.

In describing how I felt taking the quizzes to someone, I had said that they were tantalizing, but after looking the word up to confirm that I had used it correctly, I found that it was a bit off from what I wanted. I think unnerving would be more appropriate, but what would the SE community say is the best way to describe tests like these?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *unnerving* in your context, so I'm voting to close because all you're looking for is a list of synonyms that you could look up elsewhere.

Comment: -1 too little research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feeling you describe sounds like it is:

**nerve-wracking**,

the feeling of being anxious, concerned constantly about making the wrong choice, leading you to not want to make a decision.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about that one. Though, it's been so overused that it's a bit understated now. Are there any close synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

[Unnerving](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unnerving)?

> 1: to deprive of courage, strength, or steadiness
>
> 2: to cause to become nervous : upset

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "both exacting and exasperating"

Answer (score 0):

Such tests, quizzes makes  you feel **trapped**.  For such questions, tests, exams e.t.c you may use **distractive**.